# Will Personalization still work even if the IP is hashed or redacted

Tags: personalization, geo-location

I read in the Sitecore docs that setting `Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.IpHashProvider` stores the IP addresses in hashed and setting `Analytics.RedactIpAddress` to true sets all IP in xDb to `0.0.0.0`. So even if we configure this, will personalization still work?

Or are these configurations irrelevant with personalization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes it will.

Personalisation is based on the current session - it happens real-time. Any personalisation rules you normally use, will continue to work regardless of this setting.

The hashing or blanking of IP addresses affects *what gets stored in xDB*. This happens *after* any personalisation has taken place to render your page.

In short; these configuration changes only affect storage. Not active personalisation.